# I’m trying to use snap but I’m getting this error

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi4

The image:

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help?

I really don’t know what’s happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can [restart your service](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/265#issuecomment-361002259) and try your command again.

```
systemctl restart snapd.service
```